# Многоуровневая выборка в классе

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список `List<Helper> list = new List<Helper>();`

Хочу с помощью linq вытащить данные, за опр. дату. Есть вариант сделать через вложенные циклы, но хотелось бы увидеть более элегантное решение через linq.

```
class Helper
{
    public string Articule { get; set; }
    public List<Date> Dates { get; set; }

}

class Date
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Cnt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Что на выходе хотите получить?

Comment: Хочу получить list c теми элементами которые попадают под условие

Comment: С какими именно? Коллекцию `Helper` или `Articule`? Или чего?

Comment: список экземпляров класса helper

Comment: В Dates должны быть все даты исходного элемента или только искомая?

Comment: только искомая//

Comment: А почему все эти уточнения по части данных на выходе нельзя было сразу поместить в исходном вопросе? Вы получили, как минимум три ответа, которые были впоследствии удалены, после сделанных уточнений. Вам не кажется, что Вы заставили людей зря тратить свое бесценное время?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов увы, сразу не получается мысли обмозговать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.Where(l => l.Dates.Any(d => d.Data == "20170301")).ToList();
```